# Method for setting/adding value for relationship

Tags: core-data

What method will be called by Core Data on NSManagedObject when setting a value for to-one relationship? What method will be called when adding a value to to-many relationship? Thanks.

/Mikael

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like:

[Managed Object Accessor Methods - Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdAccessorMethods.html)

Comment: I've read this document and I still don't know what methods to implement in my NSManagedObject subclass. I need to know when these relationships are set so that I can do some things in my code. Thanks

Comment: @MikaelHakman These relationships are set just when you `Jake.department = departmentCTU;`

Comment: Or you can use KVO to observe the `department` of `Jake` so that anyone change `Jake`'s department you will know.

Answer (score 0):

Its like this
        managedObjectInstance.property = value;
        [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

Ex: if you want to save username in user entity it will be

_userEntity.username = @"Mikeal Hakman";
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

One to Many or Many to May always carries NSSet example

_residenceEntity.Seller = [NSSet setWithObjects:seller, nil];
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I didn't manage to formulate my question clearly enough. I'll try again.

In a subclass of NSManagedObject I need to know when to-many and to-one relationships are being changed. That includes the very first change when the object is being fetched or inserted. I try all the accessors described in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdAccessorMethods.html to no avail. I can see in my UI that the relationship is there but no accessor methods has been called on my object. Also when I remove the relationship, it goes away in UI but no methods on my object are called. Thanks.

/Mikael